# How can I increase the code coverage of this class in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, code-coverage

The parts that wont cover in the test class coverage are indicated by astriks... Can someone please look and see why they are not working... I have tried everything recommended online.

Apex Class:

public class SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC {

```
public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> triggerNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Trigger_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Trigger_Name__c != 'SEOCSMEDAL']);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:triggerNames){
        **rulesmap.put(rules.Trigger_Name__c,rules);**
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((rulesmap.get(rules.Trigger_Name__c)!=null)){
            **rules.adderror('Trigger Name already exists.');**
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeInsert2(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> surveyNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Survey_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Active__c = true]);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:surveyNames){
        **rulesmap.put(rules.Survey_Name__c,rules);**
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((rulesmap.get(rules.Survey_Name__c)!=null)){
            **rules.adderror('Active Survey Rule already created for that Survey Name.');**
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules, map<Id,Survey_Rules__c> oldmap){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> triggerNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Trigger_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Trigger_Name__c != 'SEOCSMEDAL']);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:triggerNames){
        **rulesmap.put(rules.Trigger_Name__c,rules);**
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((oldmap.get(rules.id).Trigger_Name__c!=rules.Trigger_Name__c)&&(rulesmap.get(rules.Trigger_Name__c)!=null)){
            **rules.adderror('Trigger Name already exists.');**
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeUpdate2(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules, map<Id,Survey_Rules__c> oldmap){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> surveyNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Survey_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Active__c = true]);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:surveyNames){
        **rulesmap.put(rules.Survey_Name__c,rules);**
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((oldmap.get(rules.id).Survey_Name__c!=rules.Survey_Name__c)&&(rulesmap.get(rules.Survey_Name__c)!=null)){
            **rules.adderror('Active Survey Rule already created for that Survey Name.');**
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Test code:

@isTest
public class SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC_Test {

```
@isTest
public static void testAllMethods(){
    Survey__c s1 = new Survey__c();
    s1.STAGING_STATUS__c = 'Open';
    s1.IRN__c = 111;
    s1.TRIGGER_NAME__c = 'SEOCSMEDAL';
    s1.COURSE_ID__c = 'MGMT/500';
    s1.STAGING_STATUS_DATETIME__c = System.Now();
    //insert s1;
    
    Survey__c s2 = new Survey__c();
    s2.STAGING_STATUS__c = 'Open';
    s2.IRN__c = 222;
    s2.TRIGGER_NAME__c = 'SEOCSMEDAL';
    s2.COURSE_ID__c = 'MGMT/500';
    s2.STAGING_STATUS_DATETIME__c = System.Now();
    //insert s2;
    
    Survey__c s3 = new Survey__c();
    s3.STAGING_STATUS__c = 'Open';
    s3.IRN__c = 333;
    s3.TRIGGER_NAME__c = 'SEOCSMEDAL';
    s3.COURSE_ID__c = 'MGMT/500';
    s3.STAGING_STATUS_DATETIME__c = System.Now();
    //insert s3; 
    
    List<Survey_Rules__c> surveyRules = new List<Survey_Rules__c> ();
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    map<id,Survey_Rules__c> testx=new map<id,Survey_Rules__c>();
            
    //Insert test 1
    Survey_Rules__c sr1 = new Survey_Rules__c();
    sr1.Name = 'sr1';
    sr1.Survey_Name__c = s1.Id;
    sr1.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr1';
    sr1.Active__c = true; 
    sr1.Deliver_via_Email__c = true;
    surveyRules.add(sr1);
    //SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert(surveyRules);
    
    //Insert test 2
    Survey_Rules__c sr2 = new Survey_Rules__c();
    sr2.Name = 'sr2';
    sr2.Survey_Name__c = s2.Id;
    sr2.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr1';
    sr2.Active__c = true; 
    sr2.Deliver_via_Email__c = true;
    SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert(surveyRules);
    sr2.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr2';
    //SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert(surveyRules);
    surveyRules.add(sr2);
    
    //Insert test 3
    Survey_Rules__c sr3 = new Survey_Rules__c();
    sr3.Name = 'sr3';
    sr3.Survey_Name__c = s1.Id;
    sr3.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr3';
    sr3.Active__c = true; 
    sr3.Deliver_via_Email__c = true;
    SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert2(surveyRules);
    sr3.Survey_Name__c = s3.Id;
    //SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert2(surveyRules);
    surveyRules.add(sr3);
    
    //insert surveyRules; 
    
    //Update
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:surveyRules){
        testx.put(rules.Survey_Name__c,rules);
    }
    
    //Update test 1
    sr2.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr1';
    SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeUpdate(surveyRules, testx); 
    
    //Update test 2
    sr3.Survey_Name__c = s2.Id;
    SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeUpdate2(surveyRules, testx);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Why are your `insert` statements commented out in your test class?

Comment: Abraham - I could not get them to work I kept getting null pointer errors

Comment: without them being inserted the queries (correctly) find no records in database. There are hacks around that (@seealldata, faking dummy records if Test.isRunningTest()) but they don't always work (@seealldata in empty sandbox will still fail), your best shot at it is to inspect these null pointers. Maybe you have required fields you don't populate in test, maybe there are some bugs in trigger handler. can you edit your question with exact error message and piece of code around the line number it points to

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Lindsey Wilson To cover the whole test class you have to insert the objects you are using in your class with the fields that will satisfy the conditions if you are querying that object.

As I can see in your class that you are comparing old and new data for a field you should try updating it after inserting it to list.Below is the sample test class for your reference

```
@isTest 
public class SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC_Test {
    public static testMethod void testAllMethods(){
        List<Survey_Rules__c> srList = new List<Survey_Rules__c>();
        map<Id,Survey_Rules__c> srMap = new map<Id,Survey_Rules__c>();
        Survey__c s1 = new Survey__c();
        s1.STAGING_STATUS__c = 'Open';
        s1.IRN__c = 111;
        s1.TRIGGER_NAME__c = 'SEOCSMEDAL';
        s1.COURSE_ID__c = 'MGMT/500';
        s1.STAGING_STATUS_DATETIME__c = System.Now();
        insert s1;

        Survey__c s2 = new Survey__c();
        s2.STAGING_STATUS__c = 'Open';
        s2.IRN__c = 222;
        s2.TRIGGER_NAME__c = 'SEOCSMEDAL';
        s2.COURSE_ID__c = 'MGMT/500';
        s2.STAGING_STATUS_DATETIME__c = System.Now();
        insert s2;

        Survey_Rules__c sr1 = new Survey_Rules__c();
        sr1.Name = 'sr1';
        sr1.Survey_Name__c = s1.Id;
        sr1.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr1';
        sr1.Active__c = true; 
        sr1.Deliver_via_Email__c = true;
        insert sr1;
        

        Survey_Rules__c sr2 = new Survey_Rules__c();
        sr2.Name = 'sr2';
        sr2.Survey_Name__c = s1.Id;
        sr2.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr2';
        sr2.Active__c = true; 
        sr2.Deliver_via_Email__c = true;
        insert sr2;
        srList.add(sr1);
        srList.add(sr2);
        
        sr2.Trigger_Name__c = 'sr3';
        sr2.Survey_Name__c = s2.Id;
        update sr2;
        srMap.put(sr1.Id,sr1);
        srMap.put(sr2.Id,sr2);
        Test.startTest();
        SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert(srList);
        SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeInsert2(srList);
        SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeUpdate(srMap);
        SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC.onBeforeUpdate2(srMap);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```